# how to perform sort array of integer in swift manually without methods available?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

input:

```
let arrayInt = [7,8,3,4,5,9,1,2,6]
```

output

```
let newArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

how to do that WITHOUT using `.sort` method that available in Swift? I just failed in programming test, so I want to know the answer :(

Comment: You surely tried *something.* Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: https://medium.com/@EnnioMa/back-to-the-fundamentals-sorting-algorithms-in-swift-from-scratch-fccf8a3daea3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey look at this may help you, there are more then 1 possibilities:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html

There is an example:
https://gist.github.com/tmdvs/d8edeb9bf26f2f5c3e50

EDIT: Here you have an example:

```
var unsortedArray = [7,8,3,4,5,9,1,2,6]



for i in stride(from: unsortedArray.count-1, to: 0, by: -1) {
    for j in 1...i {
        if unsortedArray[j-1] > unsortedArray[j] {
            let tmp = unsortedArray[j-1]
            unsortedArray[j-1] = unsortedArray[j]
            unsortedArray[j] = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

After that the unsortedArray is sorted.
Bubble Sort

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. – (From [answer])

Answer (score 3):

```
var unsortedArray = [7,8,3,4,5,9,1,2,6]


for i in 0..<unsortedArray.count {
    for j in 0..<unsortedArray.count{
        var temp = 0
        if unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j] {
            temp = unsortedArray[i]
            unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[j]
            unsortedArray[j] = temp
        }
    }
}
print(unsortedArray)
```

Comment: may I know the algorithm you have used here?