# matrix Sort&Transpose swift4

Tags: swift, sorting, transpose

I'm given a two dimensional array of integers as parameter and I should take it and sort. But sorting should be done manually. After sorting need should make a transpose of the sorted array and return the transposed one.

```
Input:[[3, 7, 9],[8, 6, 2],[1, 5, 4]]
Return value:[[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9]]

func sortAndTranspose(matrix: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    var isSwapped = true
    while isSwapped == true {
        isSwapped = false
        for index in 1..<matrix.count {
            if matrix[index] < matrix[index - 1] { 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean sorting should be done manually?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think OP is saying that it should sort without using `sort`/`sorted` methods...

Comment: Hmm, makes you wonder if any higher order functions are allowed.

Comment: I'm just trying find solution, if someone has idea tell me pls!
It's forbidden to use extention, import, global variables and an access identifier with function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I used `flatMap` to convert the matrix into an array, then I sorted the array using code I found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52199099/9223839). Once this was done I divided the array into a matrix

**Updated version** Make us of `swapAt` and support more than square formats. Thanks to @Rob for helping out.

```
func sortAndTranspose(matrix: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    var array = matrix.flatMap({ $0 }) //create single row array

    //manual sorting
    for i in stride(from: array.count-1, to: 0, by: -1) {
        for j in 1...i {
            if array[j-1] > array[j] {
                array.swapAt(j, j - 1)
            }
        }
    }

    //transpose sorted array back into 2D array
    var result = [[Int]]()
    let count = matrix[0].count

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        if (i < count) {
            result.append([array[i]])
        } else {
            result[i % count].append(array[i])
    }
}
```

---

Original answer

```
func sortAndTranspose(matrix: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    var array = matrix.flatMap({ $0 }) //create single row array

    //manual sorting
    for i in stride(from: array.count-1, to: 0, by: -1) {
        for j in 1...i {
            if array[j-1] > array[j] {
                let tmp = array[j-1]
                array[j-1] = array[j]
                array[j] = tmp
            }
        }
    }

    //transpose sorted array back into 2D array
    var result = [[Int]]()
    let count = matrix.count

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        if (i < count) {
            result.append([array[i]])
        } else {
            result[i % count].append(array[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Why combine these two completely unrelated (sort, transpose) actions into one function?

Comment: @Rob I was going to do that but when I tested it with a 3x2 matrix it worked fine. _Edit_ it works fine for 3x2 but not 2x3, I'll look into that.

Comment: @Alexander because I got the impression that the OP wanted a single function but the thought did cross my mind.

Comment: that's a task from my interview and I've been trying to find a solution all day and your code has worked! thank you all for your help! In future I want to help newbies like me.‍♂️

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the constructive criticism, sometimes you learn a lot by answering questions to!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well answering is your opportunity to question OP's assumptions, and to teach them new things!